# typearea warning for large DIV values

Tags: warnings, typearea

The KOMA-Script documentation (`scrguide-en.pdf`/`scrguien.pdf`) has the following in section 2.6 “Adjusting the Type Area and Page Layout”:

> **Example:** Suppose you are writing up the minutes of a meeting using the `minutes` class.
> The whole thing should be two-sided. Your company uses 12 pt Bookman font. This font, which is one of the standard PostScript fonts, is enabled in LaTeX with the command `\usepackage{bookman}`.
> Bookman is a very wide font, meaning that the individual characters are relatively wide compared to their height.
> Therefore, the default setting for `DIV` in `typearea` is too small.
> After thoroughly studying this entire chapter, you conclude that a value of 15, instead of 12, is most suitable.
> The minutes will not be bound but punched and kept in a folder, and thus no binding
> correction is necessary.
> So you write:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{minutes}
> \usepackage{bookman}
> \usepackage[DIV=15]{typearea}
> ```

Now, the `minutes` class seems to be fictional, so using instead

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,DIV=15]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bookman}
\begin{document}
X
\end{document}
```

gives me the following warning:

> ```
> Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
> (typearea)                The detected line width is about 22%
> (typearea)                larger than the heuristically estimated maximum
> (typearea)                limit of typographical good line width.
> (typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize
> (typearea)                or change papersize.
> ```

It’s all well and good that arbitrary `DIV` values can be specified, but somewhat tedious that even a reasonable example (according to the documentation) emits a warning.
Is there some way to disable this warning? I’ve thought of using the `silence` package, but since `typearea` is already loaded within the document class, it’s not straightforward to activate a warning filter before then.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference of the original example and your example is, that with the original example `DIV=15` is set *after* loading the Bookman font. So all calculations are done already using Bookman. But in your `scrartcl` example, you are using `DIV=15` *before* loading the Bookman font. So the calculations are done with Computer Modern (or Latin Modern, depending on the TeX engine). So the simple suggestion to avoid the warning is, to again do `DIV=15` *after* loading the font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bookman}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=15}
\begin{document}
X
\end{document}
```

You will find, that there is no more warning about bad type area settings.

Comment: Note: I've asked the KOMA-Script author to change the `scrartcl` example and to explain the difference.

Comment: Ah, interesting – that helps with this specific example. I’d still like a way to get `typearea` to shut up and just let me use whatever setting I want. I guess I might as well just use `geometry`…